# R concatenate a column of dataframe, make a vector, then use it in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, vector, concatenation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Tote_Type Length Width Height
L1        36     24     24
L2        33     20     20
M1        30     18     18
M2        27     16     16
S1        24     14     14
S2        20     10     10
```

I want to make a highly automated program. This dataframe is an input data. I will read in this dataframe from an excel file. Then I will loop through `tote` types like this

```
for (i in c("L1", "L2", "M1", "M2", "S1", "S2")){
    pass
}
```

The problem is, the `tote` types may change. I want to create a tool that does not need to edit R code. All the changes need to be done in Excel.

So my goal is read in an excel file as a dataframe that looks like the above, then use the first column data or part of first column data to create a vector like `c("L1" , "L2" , "M1", "M2", "S1", "S2")`, then apply this vector to the `for` loop.

I really don't know how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just do `for(i in DF$Tote_Type)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? You can create the vector using `unique()`. Lets create the data frame first:

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "
  Tote_Type Length Width Height
  L1        36     24     24
  L2        33     20     20
  M1        30     18     18
  M2        27     16     16
  S1        24     14     14
  S2        20     10     10
  ",
  header = T,
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Unique gives your desired vector:

```
> unique(df$Tote_Type)
[1] "L1" "L2" "M1" "M2" "S1" "S2"
```

The loop:

```
for (i in unique(df$Tote_Type)){
  print(i)
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "L1"
[1] "L2"
[1] "M1"
[1] "M2"
[1] "S1"
[1] "S2"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much. Appreciate.

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work